# How to run python3.7 program in RHEL without Python 3.7?

Tags: python-3.x, rhel7

I want to develop Python scripts for RHEL to check system configuration(if it is hardened as per CIS). Then i want to deploy them on servers without Python 3.7. Should i use any other version of Python? Please suggest links / ways to do this.

Comment: Ι mean, it depends on wether your program has any code specific to 3.7 that can't run on any other versions...